# How do I perform a SQL Server fulltext CONTAINS search for 'C#'

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I'm doing a full-text search for the term 'C#' like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  Book b  
WHERE CONTAINS (b.title , 'c#')
```

However, the full text search looks like it strips out the pound sign and then performs the search.

If I do a wildcard "like" search, I get correct results:

```
SELECT *
FROM  Book b  
where title like '%c#%'
```

Is there a way to do a full-text `CONTAINS` search for a term that contains a hash/pound sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the full text search is doing exactly what it's supposed to.  To get an exact match change your where clause by putting the term `C#` in double quotes.  Since an *exact match* is case sensitive by definition, you can use an or to search for both a lower case and upper case version.

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"C#" or "c#"');
```

Comment: That fixes it. I'd tried this before, but with a lowercase "c#" which didn't match anything. I guess CONTAINS is case-sensitive, but LIKE is not.

Comment: I'll be honest I'm a bit confused by the documentation when I look at it.  I'm glad this worked, but I'm curious if just upper casing 'C#' in your original answer would've worked?  Anyways I changed my answer to support case sensitivity.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. My case is a little different. I'm searching for a word preceded by the `#` symbol, say `#mytag`. The results returned are only where `mytag` is a word on its own. i.e. with no hash symbol. Any idea what this could be? I read the hash symbol could possibly be used as a wildcard for numbers when used as prefix to a word...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a sandbox to test this in but did you try `CHAR(35)` which is the pound sign?  You could set a variable and concatenate it with `CHAR(35)`, that may work.